# Under what circumctances will catch all (catch (Exception ex)) not really catch all?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-phone-7

My crash reporting system is telling me that an exception reached the Unhandled Exception handler, and looking at the code that originates this, I can't see how this is happening.. The code is fully synchronous and wrapped in a try/catch.

Clarification: This code is running on Windows Phone 7 and the exception is happening in production in an uncontrolled environment (i.e. on users' devices].

Here's the code:

```
private void LoadUserData()   
{   
    try  
    {   
        UserData = UserData.Deserialize(UserDataFileName, true);   

        // We succeeded. Backup the file, if possible.   
        if (IsoFile.Store.FileExists(UserDataFileName))   
        {   
             try  
             {   
                 IsoFile.CopyFile(UserDataFileName, UserDataFileBackupName);   
             }   
             catch (Exception ex)   
             {   
                 EventManager.Current.ShipAssert("LoadUserData.Backup", ex);   
             }   
         }   
     }   
     catch (Exception ex)   
     {   
         string currentFile = "";   
         try  
         {   
             currentFile = IsoFile.ReadAllLines(UserDataFileName);   
         }   
         catch (Exception exInner)   
         {   
             currentFile = "Exception when trying to read file: " + exInner.ToString();   
         }   
    }   
}
```

And the exception that reaches the unhandled exception handler:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (129, 54). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (129, 54). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: value, item, VotedUrls, UserData. Line 129, position 54.    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 res, String resString, String arg)    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, Int32 res, String resString, String arg)    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at    
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()    at    
System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadEndElement()    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializePrimitiveElement(LogicalType deserializeAs, Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget, String identifier, Boolean emptyValue, Boolean nullValue)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)    at    
SocialEbola.Shared.Utils.SerializableDictionary`2.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeSerializableElement(LogicalType deserializeAs, Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget, String identifier, Boolean emptyValue, Boolean nullValue)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeElementMember(MemberValueCollection members, Object fixupTarget, Hashtable internalState, Boolean& firstElement)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeMembers(MemberValueCollection members, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeComplexElement(LogicalType deserializeAs, Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget, String identifier, Boolean emptyValue, Boolean nullValue)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)    at    
SocialEbola.Lib.Serialization.SerializeHelper`1.Deserialize(Stream stream)    at    
SocialEbola.Lib.Serialization.SerializeHelper`1.Deserialize(String file, Boolean createNew)    at    
Fails.App.LoadUserData()    at    
Fails.App.Application_Launching(Object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)    at    
Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireLaunching()    at    
Microsoft.Phone.Execution.NativeEmInterop.FireOnLaunching()     at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)    at    
SocialEbola.Shared.Utils.SerializableDictionary`2.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeSerializableElement(LogicalType deserializeAs, Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget, String identifier, Boolean emptyValue, Boolean nullValue)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeElement(Accessor accessor, Fixup fixup, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.DeserializeElementMember(MemberValueCollection members, Object fixupTarget, Hashtable internalState, Boolean& firstElement)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.deserializeMembers(MemberValueCollection members, Object fixupTarget)    at    
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.D
```

This is the code for UserData.Deserialize (it's from a templated base-class):

```
public static T Deserialize(string file, bool createNew)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    T result;

    if (!store.FileExists(file))
    {
        if (createNew)
        {
            result = new T();
        }
        else
        {
            result = default(T);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(file, FileMode.Open, store))
        {
            result = Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static T Deserialize(Stream stream)
{
    T t = (T)Serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    return t;
}
```

And Serializer is defined in the base class as:

```
public static XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
```

Comment: +1 for SocialEbola. I love social viruses.

Comment: Could you show us the `UserData.Deserialize` method? It might do some asynchronous  work which throws the exception.

Comment: @Shahar Prish Are you sure that stack track originates from the code you pasted? Are you running it under Visual Studio or standalone?

Comment: @Erno: Wouldn't the exception have occurred on the async thread and not on this thread in that case? (i can paste the code, but there's nothing async about it. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Wal: That's the only method with that signature that I have. This is running as stand-alone in production on users devices (Windows Phones) and is being reported to me via a crash report mechanism I have [I will add clarification]

Comment: @ShaharPrish - I can only determine whether or not the method does anything asynchronously by looking at it.

Comment: Sure. Let me add it - but even if it does do something asynchronous - you would not have seen the exception on this callstack - it would have been on a separate callstack... So I am missing something about how this would help - will add the code in a few minutes.

Comment: @Emo: Added the coce above (2 methods and explanation about what 'Serializer' is.

Comment: Please do not post line numbers in future

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** What I would try first is Cleaning your project and rebuilding. You might not be running the code you think you are running. (ie that stack doesnt have line numbers and may not be your most recent compiled assembly)

Now if that doesnt fix it, read on

Put a breakpoint on your UnhandledException method handler and determine whether the calling thread is the same as the thread that is throwing the exception:

```
private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //add this line and put a breakpoint here.
    var threadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Log.Error("CurrentDomain_UnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}
```

If the two threadId's are different then that can explain the behaviour you see. (as @Erno stated)

If they are the same then I would, as a test, throw an explicit Exception in your code before your call to `Deserialize` to see if that is caught. eg:

```
throw new Exception("test");
UserData = UserData.Deserialize(UserDataFileName, true);
```

and then report back.

Comment: Thanks. As I clarified above, this exception is only happening in production on users devices. I cannot cause this to repro on my local emulator/machine, so I can't try all that. The callstack is reported from these devices (so it's not how the debugger interperts the result). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Shahar your code looks like it *should* catch that exception thus I would change direction and ask whether the code you are looking at is the same version in production? If unsure use reflector to decompile your production dll to ensure the code has the try catch block like the source.

Comment: I am pretty damn sure, but that's not a bad idea. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 2.0, StackOverflowException is uncatchable.  This is something that could easily be tripped by your code.  The only other uncatchable exception is the AccessViolationException in .Net 4.0.  This should only occur if you are trying to read protected memory.

I would say that StackOverflowException is your most likely suspect.  Check your code for recursive functions that aren't capped off and try stepping through a debugger to see what condition is causing it.

Comment: How do you come to that conclusion given the stack shows InvalidOperationException?

Comment: @Brian Nickel: I may be missing something, but like wal said, the process did not failfast - it actually went through the trouble of running the Unhandled exception handler. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian, you're absolutely correct that exception processing is terminated on a StackOverflowException That is because exception processing walks the call stack looking for catch-blocks that match the exception type and finally-blocks that must get executed. If the stack is in an error state, that processing cannot occur. However, a stack overflow exception is going to be due to deep recursion or very large amounts or sizes of value types on the call stack. From the code shown, I don't see anything that suggests those problems. I expect the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning and applying some excpetion processing best practices.

Don't use exceptions for flow control (as you are doing), use them to report and handle error conditions.

Catch blocks should recover from the error condition, either partially or completely, and potentially rethrow the exception or throw a new (possibly more specific exception). Do not put business logic in the catch block (as you are doing). Doing so can have one exception mask another.

Only catch exceptions that you are going to (at least partially) recover from, or in order to throw a more specific exception. Since exceptions are caught by type, this means you should practically never catch System.Exception: it is far too general for you to recover from.

By the same token, do not throw exceptions that are too general, such as System.Exception. Study the exceptions already defined in the .Net Framework Class Library, or create specific exception types that derive directly or indirectly from System.Exception.

Since the catch blocks for a given try block are evaluated in order, be sure to place catch blocks for more derived exception types before catch blocks for less derived exceptoin types.

Any good C# programming reference should provide guidance on correct use and best practices on throwing and catching exceptions.

With this in mind:
 - What exception types are being caught in line 14? Make that explicit.
 - Is it possible for the code in line 16 to throw an exception? If so, what exception processing would occur?
 - Why is the variable declared on line 22 scoped to the catch block? What is the value of assigning to it on line 29, given that it goes out of scope right after that?

Sort these things out in your code, then step through it with a debugger and I believe you've spot the culprit right away.

Comment: Thanks for the 101. :) A few questions to clarify your answer so I can better answer it... What do you mean by "Don't use exceptions for flow control"? What am I doing here that is flow control? There's no way to check for the validity of an XML file that's performant - the only way to do this is to call the parse method - if it fails, it means soemthing wrong happened to the XML and it cannot be parsed. How would you suggest I handle that speicifc case?

Comment: That's a good question. Inside the outermost catch-block of LoadUserData you have logic which only gets executed if an exception gets thrown in the outermost try-block. That's flow control -- directing which statements get executed under which circumstances. Instead use catch-blocks exclusively for recovering from exceptions, logging them, transforming one exception type into another. Flow control statements in C# include if-then, foreach, etc. Don't use exception processing for doing what you can with the flow control constructs.

Comment: Gotcha. So the issue you are talking about is the fact that the catch() contains logic which could have been moved out of the catch, after setting a "errorOccurred" local variable to true in the catch. Am I getting this about right? If so, I understand what you are saying - good point. However, the problem I have is way before that - the catch(Exception ex) is not catching all Exceptions, or so it seems, which means there is a more basic issue here which would not be solved by re-engineering the code for more correct exception handling.

Comment: One of the problems with nesting exception processing (try- and catch-blocks) is the ease with which one exception can be masked by another. It's quite likely that the behavior you belive you are seeing is explained by this phenomenon.

Comment: Okay, I now see what you mean, even though I have never seen the behavior you describe where an Exception that was caught somehoe "escapes" the catch block instead of a different one - but then again, most of my experience is on server development in .NET and not Silverlight. I will refactor the code and do another release of this and see if it solves the problem - still - seems like a .NET bug more than anything else (unless you can see a concrete example where what you describe can happen in the real world)

Comment: The exception processing behavior and best practices are not different between Silverlight and .NET. No one can say that there are no bugs in either platform, if there were a problem with exception processing then there would be a *lot* of broken code out there. The likelihood of the bug being in .NET/Silverlight rather than in your code is rather slim. I am the first to admit that can be hard to see at times. Best luck!